# Reading JSON file with different datatypes

Tags: json

I am trying to read a JSON file that contains following data

```
"{\"studentData\":[{\"Name\":\"Graham\",\"aggregate\":\"86\",\"regular\":\"true\",\"percentages\":[{\"sub1\":\"69\",\"sub2\":\"97\",\"sub3\":\"90\"}]},{\"Name\":\"Finley\",\"aggregate\":\"96\",\"regular\":\"false\",\"percentages\":[{\"sub1\":\"95\",\"sub2\":\"91\",\"sub3\":\"73\"}]},{\"Name\":\"Carrillo\",\"aggregate\":\"93\",\"regular\":\"true\",\"percentages\":[{\"sub1\":\"90\",\"sub2\":\"84\",\"sub3\":\"80\"}]},{\"Name\":\"Crosby\",\"aggregate\":\"68\",\"regular\":\"true\",\"percentages\":[{\"sub1\":\"63\",\"sub2\":\"92\",\"sub3\":\"77\"}]},{\"Name\":\"Small\",\"aggregate\":\"88\",\"regular\":\"true\",\"percentages\":[{\"sub1\":\"65\",\"sub2\":\"80\",\"sub3\":\"81\"}]}]}"
```

I have following code so far

```
    const data = require("./testdata.json");
    
    /*Explore the JSON file and return required JSON data*/
    console.log(data)
```

when I run the code, I see the output in console
But how do I refer to each item in the data
e.g. Name, Regular

When I try to access using below code,

```
   console.log(data.studentData.Name)
```

I get error

```
   console.log(data.studentData.Name)
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
```

Comment: You have to loop through it. There are multiple names but what you have is an attempt to get them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

`data.studentData` is an array so you need to loop through each value.

With `forEach` for example:

```js
data.studentData.forEach((individualStudentData) => {
  console.log(individualStudentData.Name);
  //Do your thing (:
});
```

Or:

- `for (let individualStudentData of data.studentData)`
- a function like `.map(() => { ... }`
- etc. ;)

Comment: Tried , but does not work, Tried to use  ~~~ console.log(data.studentData); ~~~ it gives undefined..

Comment: Okay have you tried removing the starting & ending `"`, as well as the backslash `\\` in your JSON? For now your JSON is not valid :) You can always check here [JSON parser online](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: FYI If you got this JSON from a web query, you can manually process it with things like `.replace('\','')` on a string and use the `JSON.parse([string here])` to parse it

Comment: it's working, i added JSON.parse with existing data, and then used the foreach , Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like data.studentData is actually a JSON Array. So if you wanted to log every name, you'd need to do

```
const data = require("./testdata.json");
data.studentData.forEach( student => console.log(student.Name));
```

Comment: I am getting error   data.studentData.forEach( student => console.log(student.Name));
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: maybe try using data["studentData"] instead. If that still doesn't work, then there may be a parsing problem.